# How to reference type class-polymorphic variables in a theorem type?

Tags: typeclass, coq

I have written a Haskell-style `Functor` type class:

```coq
Class Functor (f: Type -> Type) := {
  map {a b: Type}: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b);
  map_id: forall (a: Type) (x: f a), map id x = x
}
```

Where `id` has the obvious definition.

Now, I've proven instances of `Functor` for `list` and the function type. But I want to prove statements about *any* functor. To start with, I want to prove what's essentially a tautology: a restatement of the `map_id` for any functor.

```coq
Theorem map_id_restatement: forall (F: Type -> Type), 
  Functor F -> forall T (x: F T), map id x = x.
```

The idea being to prove this theorem I would simply `apply map_id`. But I get an error when I try to start proving this:

```coq
Toplevel input, characters 88-91:
Error:

Could not find an instance for "Functor F" in environment:

F : Type -> Type
T : Type
x : F T
```

But the `Functor F` instance should be already in scope due to the assumption in the type. Why is it not recognized?

Edit:

OK, I figured out I could make it work by quantifying the `Functor F`:

```coq
Theorem map_id_restatement: forall (F: Type -> Type) (finst: Functor F),
  forall T (x: F T), map id x = x.
Proof. apply @map_id. Qed.
```

Why is this necessary? Interestingly, it *doesn't* work if I don't explicitly give a name to the functor instance (i.e. if I just write `(_: Functor F)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a bug or not, but notice that when you write something like `Functor F -> SomeType`, you are implicitly saying that `SomeType` does not depend on the `Functor` instance, which is not true in your case: the full type of your theorem, printing all implicit arguments, would be something like:

```coq
Theorem map_id_restatement: forall (F: Type -> Type) (finst: Functor F),
  forall T (x: F T), @map F fints T T (@id T) x = x.
```

If you replace `finst` by `_`, you get

```coq
Theorem map_id_restatement: forall (F: Type -> Type) (_: Functor F),
  forall T (x: F T), @map F _ T T (@id T) x = x.
```

which can't really be type-checked, since `_` is not really a variable name.

Notice that, if you bind `Functor F` anonymously before the colon, Coq accepts it:

```coq
Theorem map_id_restatement (F: Type -> Type) (_ : Functor F) :
  forall T (x: F T), map (@id T) x = x.
Proof. apply @map_id. Qed.
```

Presumably, here Coq is treating the `_` in a different way, and replacing it by an automatically generated name, instead of actually leaving it unnamed. You can also use the following form, which works both under the `forall` or before the colon:

```coq
Theorem map_id_restatement (F: Type -> Type) : forall `(Functor F),
  forall T (x: F T), map (@id T) x = x.
Proof. apply @map_id. Qed.
```